# skip specific rows while printing in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can I skip specific rows while printing

for example I have a variable with 3 select statements as

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql= 'select 1  
select 2
select 3'
```

Now I want to print only by executing **print(@sql)**

```
select 1
select3
```

ie :skipping **select 2**
is that possible

Comment: You want to use SQL -- which is designed for processing tables and columns -- to control the printing of a string?  It is probably possible, but you are using the wrong tool.  Store the separate lines in a table, and you can take advantage of SQL functionality.

Comment: Or use some separator between select statements.

Comment: @PareshJ can u please elaborate

Comment: I know but i want that query can I get that @GordonLinoff

Comment: @noname . . . There is probably a better way to solve the actual problem you have, such as by storing each line as a separate row in a table.

Comment: @noname : Check this link, it will help you : http://www.queryingsql.com/2013/09/querying-microsoft-sql-server-functions.html

Comment: `REPLACE(@sql,'select 2','')`

Comment: As @Igor commented, `replace(@sql, 'select 2'+char(13)+char(10), '')` will be better to remove the row.

Comment: what on earth for? why insert `select 2` into the string and then immediately decide you don't want to see it? Perhaps you are trying to distil the actual problem into a small example - but in so doing you aren't really explaining what you need.